# traversing multiple files and opening them

Tags: python, file, traversal

I am new to python and not adept to it. I need to traverse a huge list of directories which contain zipped files within them. While this can be done via the method,

```
for file in list:
 for filename in file:
  with open.gizp(filename) as fileopen:
   for line in fileopen:
     process
```

The time taken would be take a few days. Would i be able to use any function that allows me to traverse other parts of the directory concurrently to perform the same function and not have any repeats in the traversal?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Move the heavy processing to a separate program, then call that program with subprocess to keep a certain number of parallel processes running:

```
import subprocess
import time
todo = []
for file in list:
   for filename in file:
       todo.append(filename)
running_processes = []
while len(todo)>0:
    running_processes = [p for p in running_processes if p.poll() is None]
    if len(running_processes)<8:
       target = todo.pop()
       running_processes.append( subprocess.Popen(['python','process_gzip.py',target]) )
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open many files concurrently. For instance:

```
files = [gzip.open(f,"rb") for f in fileslist]
processed = [process(f) for f in files]
```

(btw, don't call your files list "`list`", or a list of files "`file`", since they are reserved words by the language and do not describe what the object really is in your case).

Now it is going to take about the same time, since you always process them one at a time. So, is it the processing of them that you want to parallelize? Then you want to look at `threading` or `multiprocessing`.

Are you looking for `os.path.walk` to traverse directories? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). You can also do:

```
for folder in folderslist:
    fileslist = os.listdir(folder)
    for file in fileslist:
        ....
```

Are you interested by `fileinput` to iterate over lines from multiple input streams? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html, `fileinput.hook_compressed` seems to handle gzip).

Comment: Will this not run out of file descriptors?